# Setting ActiveMQ Objectmessage serializable from Scala

Tags: scala, serialization, activemq-classic

After an ActiveMQ version change (from 5.9.0 r4 to r4) it is necessary to mark the `ObjectMessage` of ActiveMQ serializable explicitly, as written here: http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html. Setting the environment variable as suggested (`-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"`) works fine, however, that is not an elegant solution in our case. I need to set it up from the Scala source. Currently the connection is set up something like this:

```
val properties = new java.util.Properties()
properties.setProperty(javax.naming.context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory")
properties.setProperty(javax.naming.context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616")
val context = new InitialContext(properties)
val topicConnection = context.lookup("ConnectionFactory").asInstanceOf[TopicConnectionFactory].createTopicConnection
```

I don't find the point where I could insert the suggested `factory.setTrustAllPackages(true)`. Could anyone either tell how to do this in our case, or how to set up the `org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES` environment variable from Scala? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following static line of code and it works:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES", """*""")
```